# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Korean Language's [Moderator election #2](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

[image: Vladhagen]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!